# Trying to make selector dynamic with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello stackoverflow:  I am trying to make the `$('.TextBoxColors-')` part of my code dynamic.
I am looking for the `i` variable in the for-loop to assign this value depending on the `if`.
I have tried many things like `$('.TextBoxColors-${i}')`, `$('.TextBoxColors-').value(i)` as in  `$('.TextBoxColors-').value(i).css('background-color', 'green')`,
but nothing works so far.

This is the javascript/jquery:

```js
let timeArray   = ["9","10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17"]
let currentTime = parseInt(moment().format("H"));

for (i=0; i< 9; i++) {
  if (currentTime < parseInt(timeArray[i])) {
    $('.TextBoxColors-9').css('background-color', 'gray')
    $('.TextBoxColors-10').css('background-color', 'gray')
    $('.TextBoxColors-11').css('background-color', 'gray')
    $('.TextBoxColors-12').css('background-color', 'gray')
  }
  if (currentTime == timeArray[i]) {
    $('.TextBoxColors-13').css('background-color', 'Tomato')
  }
  
  if (currentTime > timeArray.indexOf("currentTime",currentTime)) {

    $('.TextBoxColors-14').css('background-color', 'green')
    $('.TextBoxColors-15').css('background-color', 'green')
    $('.TextBoxColors-16').css('background-color', 'green')
    $('.TextBoxColors-17').css('background-color', 'green')
  }
}
```

These are two of the divs where I want this to happen:

```html
<!-- 2:00PM-->
<div class="input-group input-group-lg field-size Timer" >
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-lg">2 PM</span>
  </div>

  <textarea type="text" class="TextBoxColors-14 form-control" aria-label="2:00 PM"     
    aria-label describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"></textarea>
  
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="saveToDo-5"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" style="font-size:18px;"></i>
  </button>
</div>

<!-- 3:00PM-->
<div class="input-group input-group-lg field-size" >
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-lg">3 PM</span>
  </div>
  <textarea type="text" class="TextBoxColors-15 form-control" aria-label="3:00 AM"
    aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"></textarea>
  
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="saveToDo-0">
    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" style="font-size:18px;"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not use w3schools to learn JS. Anyway, you don't want to use classnames (or IDs) with running numbers, that's bad practice and basically never necessary. You can use `$('.TextBoxColors').eq(9)` instead, this will select all elements of the class, then pick the 10th element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Chris.  I am just one week into JS and jQuery.  So, what you just posted `$('.TextBoxColors').eq(9)` is something I am still to get it to make sense to me.  Thanks!

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/kq5owf6y/ (it's quite simple: if a selector matches more than one element, jQuery returns a list of elements. You can use `eq()` to narrow it down to a single element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is close:

```
$('.TextBoxColors-${i}')
```

But for template string literals you need to use back-ticks, not single-quotes:

```
$(`.TextBoxColors-${i}`)
```

Alternatively you can just concatenate the value to the string:

```
$('.TextBoxColors-' + i)
```

Comment: Great! The second one did it for me! Thanks!  How do I choose this as my answer?